# Node pug form button action not working from app.js

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have an index.pug page that is:

```
html
    head
        title= title
    body
        h1= message
        form(method="get" action="/foo")
    button(type="submit") run foo
```

and in my app.js I have:

```
app.get('/foo', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Its come here");
    res.render('index', { title: 'hello', message: 'hello' });
});
```

But when I click the button it does nothing. Am I doing something stupid?

Can't work out why any ideas appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Indent the button.  It needs to be **within** the form.

Comment: @zero298 I did try that but it shows me this error: Invalid indentation, you can use tabs or spaces but not both

Comment: Then check your indentation for consistency.  What IDE are you using?  Most have a mechanism to make white space visible and discernable (tabs vs spaces).

Comment: I'm just using sublime, what IDE do you recommend for this?

Comment: Sublime is fine.  Look at this answer to see how to render whitespace within Sublime and ensure that you are using consistent whitespace characters.  [Sublime Text 3 - show whitespace charcters](https://askubuntu.com/a/881655/32996).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indent the `button` so that it is a child element of the `form`.

```
html
    head
        title= title
    body
        h1= message
        form(method="get" action="/foo")
            button(type="submit") run foo
```

Comment: One more thing where can I read documentation on the pug attributes to use for eg images and also css?

Comment: @Sam What do you mean?  Pug's documentation is here: [Pug API](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html).  You should be keeping your CSS and pug files separate.

Comment: I mean I want to add images and style it up a bit and only add images if the user clicks. I checked the API but under this I cannot find img https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html

Comment: @Sam it would be the same for any other element that you want to use in Pug: `img(src="some-url.png")`.  `img` is the tag you want to use and your attributes go in the parentheses.

Comment: yep thanks, only thing is does it work different for this than normal html images. As I have the image in a folder images and referencing it like         img(src='../images/image.jpg' , alt='some image') and it's not finding it :(

Answer (score 1):

```
html
    head
        title= title
    body
        h1= message
        form(method="get" action="/foo")
          input(type="submit", value="run foo")
```

**button(type="submit") run foo** replace it with **input(type="submit", value="run foo")** It will work

Comment: I was also facing this issue solved it after many hours of struggle so I just point out my mistake here,

 1. please check button type in code (I had button type button "button" which should be submit for post method).
2. align your code as suggested by everyone